# Python Requests module, Json, & APIs

Tags: python, python-requests

1. I need to identify any accounts that the "account_type" in the API
   is listed as "Unknown" instead of "Linked" from an API.
2. I will need to then compare the "owner_id" field we identified as "Unknown" "account_type" against the owner_id's listed in a csv.
3. I will then need to post fields from the matching accounts csv to another API.

I am having a problem figuring out how to generate the list of owner_id that match the "Unknown" "account_type" and then compare them against the accounts that match the owner_id in a csv. Any help would be appreciated. I have listed how far I have gotten below and a short snippet of one account from the api. Thanks!

```
# This is what I started with:
import requests  
import json   

r = requests.get ("https://chapi.cloudhealthtech.com/v1/aws_accounts?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")   
data = r.json()
```

Response data:

```
{
  "aws_accounts": [  
    {  
      "id": XXXXXXXXXXXX,  
      "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",  
      "amazon_name": "XXXXXXXX",  
      "owner_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",  
      "hide_public_fields": false,  
      "region": "global",  
      "created_at": "2018-05-09T10:31:19Z",  
      "updated_at": "2018-10-24T22:02:49Z",  
      "account_type": "Linked",  
      "vpc_only": true,  
      "cluster_name": "XXX",  
      "status": {  
        "level": "yellow",  
        "last_update": "2018-12-09T13:25:01Z"  
      },  
      "authentication": {  
        "protocol": "assume_role",  
        "assume_role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/CloudHealthXAccountReaderRole",  
        "assume_role_external_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"  
      },  
      "billing": {  
        "is_consolidated": false  
      },  
      "cloudtrail": {  
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if your csv file looks like this:

```
id,sample_data
1,sample
2,sample
3,sample
4,sample
5,sample
```

try following code:

```
import requests
import csv  

r = requests.get("https://chapi.cloudhealthtech.com/v1/aws_accounts", params={"api_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"})   
data = r.json()

# we read csv file and create list with ids that we should post
with open('ids.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    # skip column names row
    next(csv_reader, None)
    ids = [row[0] for row in csv_reader]

# we parse through our aws_accounts to get Unknown types and which ids in our list
accounts_to_post = []
for account in data["aws_accounts"]:
    if account["account_type"] == "Unknown" and account["id"] in ids:
        accounts_to_post.append(account)

# at last, we post those accounts to your api
r = requests.post('your_api_url', data = {'accounts':accounts_to_post})
```

Since your question details a little bit blurry, it can be quite complicated. Also I have no idea how your accounts should be outputted to api, so I brought the simplest solution.